# Can I interpret http_build_query($_POST) so I can save it to the database in CakePHP?

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using CakePhp and jQuery in my application of FormBuilder.
 I am having form as like

```
<form action="/cake_1.2.1.8004/index.php/results/submit1" method="post"
                                                          id="ResultSubmit1Form">
    <fieldset style="display: none;">
        <input type="hidden" value="POST" name="_method"/>     
    </fieldset>

    <div class="input text">
        <label for="1">Doj</label>
        <input type="text" value="" style="width: 300px;" id="1" name="Doj"/>
    </div>

    <div class="input text">
        <label for="2">Name</label>
        <input type="text" value="" style="width: 300px;" id="2" name="Name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input textarea">
        <label for="3">Address</label>
        <textarea style="height: 300px;" id="3" rows="6" cols="30" name="Address"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input text">
        <label for="4">Age</label>
        <input type="text" value="" style="width: 200px;" id="4" name="Age"/>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to get all the values entered in the form.

Using jQuery Form plugin i have used the following code to retrieve the values like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").eq(0).click(function (){

            var serializedFormStr = $("#ResultSubmit1Form :input[value]").serialize();  
            alert(serializedFormStr);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/cake_1.2.1.8004/index.php/results/submit1",
                data: serializedFormStr,
                success: function(msg){
                    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg);
                }//success
            });//ajax
        });
    });//ready
</script>
```

The `alert(serializedFormStr);` shows as

```
        _method=POST&Doj=07%2F09%2F2009&Name=aruna&Address=xyz&Age=22
```

same I retrieved in my Cakephp controller as

```
   function submit1()
   {
       echo "In controller  ".http_build_query($_POST);//echoes correctly
   }
```

How can I get the individual datas from this query string so that I can save it my database.
Please suggest me..

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with this and discovered that http_build_query has three arguments available "since 5.1.2 The arg_separator parameter was added. " ( local Ms-windows file: mk:@MSITStore:D:\Reference\o-q\php\php_manual.chm::/res/function.http-build-query.html   on web as http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php )

When I did a $_POST var dump my second and third varibale names were coming out as amp;rowsPerPage and amp;startNumber the leading & had been eaten

For whatever reason I had to do this in what I was doing,

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
   array(
    'whereRequest' => $whereRequest,
    'rowsPerPage' => '20',
'startNumber' => '0'
   )
   ,'','&'
);
```

the second argument (numeric_prefix - which is a string) was not needed in my case, and I explicitly set arg_separator parameter to '&', which was I am sure, the default any way.

The help file examples indicated `&ampamp;` as an option but that did not work,

For what ever reason everything went ok after I explicitly set the arg_separator parameter to: '&'

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it... why are you calling `http_build_query`?  You just need to look at `$_POST['Doj']` surely.

You can loop through $_POST like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    echo 'The value of ' . $key . ' is ' . $value;
```

Or get an array of all the keys:

```
$keys = array_keys($_POST);
// $keys is now array('Doj', 'Name', 'Address', 'Age')
```

Does that help?

Comment: Actually i dont knew the fieldname Doj in my controller.So i am sending both the fieldname and its value and want to save both of them in the Table.